# how to access the Model Classes in J query?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

how to access the Model Classes in Jquery  in asp.net mvc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can always assign values of flat items (non complex types) to js variables using <%%> tags in ur views

```
var abc = '<%=Model.ABC%>';
```

now u can use abc as a javascript variable

Answer (score 3):

Model classes are part of server side. You can't just access them by jQuery (and any other client-side javascript)